# Sympy: commutator with product of operators

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to calculate the commutator of a complicated expression and I'm not getting the result that I want to obtain. Please find below the problem:

```
from sympy.physics.secondquant import *
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import simplify

a = symbols('a')

c = Commutator(Bd(a)*B(a),Bd(a))

print(simplify(c.doit()))
```

The output is:

```
CreateBoson(a)*AnnihilateBoson(a)*CreateBoson(a) - CreateBoson(a)**2*AnnihilateBoson(a)
```

which does not help at all.

If I try `Commutator(Bd(a)-B(a),Bd(a))` instead of `Commutator(Bd(a)*B(a),Bd(a))`:

```
from sympy.physics.secondquant import *
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import simplify

a = symbols('a')

c = Commutator(Bd(a)-B(a),Bd(a))

print(simplify(c.doit()))
```

I get the desired result: -1.

Does someone have an idea how to fix this issue?